# Logitech H600 on Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial - NO sound!

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, alsa, logitech

**Running Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial LTS.**

I'm quite frustrated at this point.  I have tried the solutions that I could find on the net for this problem but nothing seems to solve it.

I am fairly new to Ubuntu but enjoying it thoroughly!  The only pain I have is my headset has no sound at all.  It is detected just fine in the sound settings and I can select it but there is not sound.

I have tried re-pairing as suggested in other topics but to no avail.  I have tried completely removing this thing called unity and re-installing it but same thing.  So then I installed something called pulseaudio volume control and I noticed it shows "Headset (Unplugged)" which I have no clue if it means anything.

I built a Windows 10 VM machine on the ubuntu localhost and the headset works perfectly there.  No issues at all.

PLEASE could someone assist me in trying to figure out why this is happening?  It is frustrating me endlessly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I had a similar issue on 16.04 (I'm not on 17.04 and have not tried since) and resolved it by `sudo apt-get install -y blueman pavucontrol`

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem on this link:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure

Step1 solve it for me when I ran this command:

> sudo apt-get update;sudo apt-get dist-upgrade; sudo apt-get install pavucontrol linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils lightdm ubuntu-desktop  linux-image-`uname -r` libasound2; sudo apt-get -y --reinstall install linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils lightdm ubuntu-desktop  linux-image-`uname -r` libasound2; killall pulseaudio; rm -r ~/.pulse*; ubuntu-support-status; sudo usermod -aG `cat /etc/group | grep -e '^pulse:' -e '^audio:' -e '^pulse-access:' -e '^pulse-rt:' -e '^video:' | awk -F: '{print $1}' | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's:,$::g'` `whoami`